# NSDateFormatter dateFromString returns incorrect date

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to use `NSDateFormatter` in my app which takes a date string and formats it to an `NSDate` so that I can do Date Comparisons, however I am finding when I use dateFromString and format it the date is losing one day.

```
NSString *dateString = @"02-06-2012";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
NSLog(@"My Date = %@", dateFromString);
[dateFormatter release];
```

This outputs to the console:

> My Date = 2012-06-01 23:00:00 +0000

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I don't believe that Dhruv's answer is correct. In fact, it's not clear there's any problem at all. You just seem to have an incorrect expectation of what should happen and/or interpretation of what's happening.

`NSDate` represents a moment in time. This moment does not have one unique name. It will be known by different names in different places and under different naming systems (time zones, calendars). `NSDate` doesn't deal with any of this, except lamely in its `-description` method, where it has to produce a string representation of that moment.

Second, a string like "02-06-2012" doesn't specify a precise moment in time. First of all, it's just a date with no time information, so `NSDateFormatter` just defaults to the first moment for that date. Second, it doesn't specify the time zone. The first moment of the calendar day is a different moment in each time zone. Unless you specify a time zone with `-setTimeZone:` or the string itself carries time zone information, `NSDateFormatter` assumes that any date strings you ask it to parse are in the current time zone.

So, your `dateFromString` object represents the first moment of the specified date, 02-06-2012, in your time zone. I expect this is what you wanted. However, you then got confused by the way that `NSDate` describes itself when logged. As I said, `NSDate` has to pick some "name" (string representation) for the moment it represents and which name it picks is fairly arbitrary. These days it is picking the name that the moment is known by in UTC. I gather from the log output shown in your question that you are located at UTC+0100. So, the date may look like it's one day earlier but it really is the same moment you specified.  In other words, "2012-06-01 23:00:00 +0000" and "2012-06-02 00:00:00 +0100" are two equivalent names for exactly the same moment in time. You just aren't used to seeing the first one and misinterpreted it.

The lesson is that you have to stop relying on `NSDate`'s self-description to be in any particular time zone. Really, you have to not rely on anything about it, since it's not documented. In fact, the docs for `-[NSDate description]` state, "The representation is not guaranteed to remain constant across different releases of the operating system."

Dhruv's solution *seems* to help merely because it causes `NSDateFormatter` and `-[NSDate description]` to agree on the time zone. But that's unreliable. It wouldn't work on Snow Leopard, for example, because `-[NSDate description]` used the local time zone instead of UTC in that version of the frameworks.

More importantly, though, it alters the actual moment represented by the `NSDate` object you get from `NSDateFormatter`'s interpretation of your date string. I suspect you really want that to have a specific meaning – you want the string to be interpreted as being in the local time zone – and his solution thwarts your intent.

tl;dr: you were getting the date you wanted all along; don't rely on `-[NSDate description]`; don't use Dhruv's solution

Comment: Hi Ken, Thanks for the detailed reply, what would you recommend I do or use? In my app I need to check is equal to or greater than a specific hard coded date I need to put in my app.  Thanks

Comment: You have to decide what moment you really mean. Is the hard-coded date meant to be interpreted as being in some specific, fixed time zone (like that of your company's home office)? Or is it supposed to be interpreted as being in the user's time zone? If the former, you should set the fixed time zone on the date formatter. If the latter, you can leave it as the default or you can explicitly set it to `[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]` (or `+systemTimeZone`).

Comment: Thanks Ken I will give that a go - the fixed time is basically a specific date so if you open the App and your based anywhere in the world it should use the specific date and see if today is greater or equal, we are doing this as we have to display different info in our app from a certain date. Your explanation also makes more sense so I will mark up your answer. Thanks

Comment: This is actually a really good piece of explanation regarding misassumptions on `NSDate` and `NSDateFormatter` concepts.

Answer (score 49):

Try adding this lines to your code,

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT+0:00"]];
```

or

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
```

**SWIFT update :**

Code from quetion,

```
let dateString = "02-06-2012"
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
var dateFromString : NSDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)!
println("My Date \(dateFromString)")
```

And Solution ,

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "GMT")
```

OR

```
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+0:00")
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be a non-generic solution? What if the device is not on GMT?

Comment: @stavash That's the point, GMT is the same as UTC, or Universal Time.  It's the one standardized time zone that everyone can use and it never changes (due to daylight savings time, etc).  This is how iOS stores dates/times....

Comment: So would using GMT work in the app across all time zones? I'm actually getting the current date NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init]; then comparing it to a string as above.

Comment: Granted you know that input time is in UTC, this is a lot better answer then the currently checked one. +1

Comment: I love Google! (brought me here) THX :)

Comment: Thank God.. You are a savior. Was trying different date formats but none of them was working. This is the perfect answer.