# Converting NSString to NSDate is generating wrong value

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently i have a NSString Value which contains following date as current date

```
(lldb) po self.currentDate
(NSString *) $5 = 0x002ca8d0 2013-03-29
```

But when i convert this NSString to NSDate , it is showing wrong value

```
NSDate *myCurrentDate  = [dateFormatterForCurrentDate dateFromString:self.currentDate];

(lldb) po myCurrentDate
(NSDate *) $4 = 0x002cf030 2013-03-28 18:30:00 +0000
```

Comment: **That is correct!!!** This is shown in timezone relative from GMT.

Comment: Anoop is correct. See my [answer to an earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273001/nsdateformatter-datefromstring-returns-incorrect-date/11273812#11273812).

Answer (score 3):

Try with this code, for considering local time zone....

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatterForCurrentDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatterForCurrentDate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[dateFormatterForCurrentDate setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
NSDate *myCurrentDate  = [dateFormatterForCurrentDate dateFromString:self.currentDate];
```

Hope this is helpful...

Answer (score 2):

set this date format:

```
    [dateFormatterForCurrentDate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```

and also check [Date Formatters](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) in developer.apple.com

may be it is useful to you.