# NSDateFormatter parses wrong?

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

The following code

```
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSString* source = @"11/30/2012";
    NSDate* date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:source];
    NSLog(@"%@ → %@", source, date);
```

results in this output

> 11/30/2012 → 2012-11-29 15:00:00 +0000

I expected the times to be the same. (ie right 2012-11-30 00:00:00 +0000) *...because I know the input time is already in UTC. So output should be same time if output time is also output in UTC.* Is this a time zone issue? The left string date should have no timezones specified and NSDate should output UTC dates?

Comment: Yes, it's a timezone issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSDateFormatter dateFromString returns incorrect date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11273001/nsdateformatter-datefromstring-returns-incorrect-date)

Comment: That post does not have a correct and concise answer checked as correct. The checked answer is just too long and not to the point.

Comment: A bit more clarification: if you know input time is UTC, then you need to set timezone of NSDateFormatter to UTC, or it would default to another timezone (not sure here, possibly the timezone of the current device). If you expect another timezone if input time, then NSDateFormatter should be set to that instead. (so this has got nothing to do with NSDate of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it.

I added

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
```

And now get

> 11-30-2012 → 2012-11-30 00:00:00 +0000

...because I know input time is already in UTC. If NSDate reports another time in UTC, then the parser (NSDateFormatter) parsed incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

printing a NSDate directly always will print the date and time in the standart format with timezone of GMT (+0000), while the creation takes the system's timezone in account.

You seem to be 9 hours after GMT/UTC.

Comment: This has got nothing to do with NSDate, it was an issue with parsing using NSDateFormatter that needs to be set to UTC timezone. A moderator deleted my answer which fixed it: `[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];`

Comment: Your comment is quite funny. My answer explains that there is a mismatch between the timezone when printing an date directly and when using a date formatter. the implicit solution is to set the formatters timezone. I couldnt advice to use UTC, as at the time I wrote this answer, you handt told us that the date is in utc. so your down vote is more than unjustified. I dont know, why your answer got deleted, but I am not responsible for it.